# [UnsafeControlException: A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, web-config, spwebconfigmodification

When the upgrade of 2007 to 2010 took place i started to get errors for my webparts on my website as mentioned below:
Error[1]

Web Part Error: A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The type could not be found or it is not registered as safe.

Show Error Details

```
[UnsafeControlException: A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The type could not be found or it is not registered as safe.]
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SafeControls.GetTypeFromGuid(Guid guid, Guid solutionId, String assemblyFullName, String typeFullName, Boolean throwIfNotFound) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.CreateWebPartsFromRowSetData(Boolean onlyInitializeClosedWebParts)
```

Comment: Have you tried re-deploying your webparts after the upgrade to see if it helps?

Comment: in my case it was because i was working in new UAT farm which have not that Webpart Deployed at all. check that you are not doing the same mistake

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the web part type as safe control in the web applications "web.config" file and in the **configuration > SharePoint > SafeControls** section. The general format is like below:

Just replace **AssemblyName**, **AssemblyVersion**, **AssemblyCulture**, **AssemblyPublicKeyToken**, The class name of the web-part and **The class name of the web-part** with the information to your web-part.

Answer (score 0):

This is usally shown very clear in the Trace logs. Check the LOGS directory on your front ends and search for the error.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a step by step tutorial to track the error cause:
http://www.bluedoglimited.com/SharePointThoughts/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=189